# Conditions for intersection of two lines

Tags: graphing-functions

I came across a STEP III($2010, Q5$) problem which involves finding the point of intersection between the curve with the equation $$n(m-1)x+m(n-1)y=amn \tag{1}$$
and
$$mx+ny=amn \tag{2}$$

where $m$ and $n$ are real constants that satisfy 
$$0<m<n<1 \tag{3}$$

Equating $(1)$ with $(2)$ yields
$$(mn-n-m)(x+y)=0 \tag{4}$$

I then simply solved for $x$ and $y$ simultaneously in terms of $m$ and $n$.

However, the mark scheme seems to offer a less arduous alternative and is stated as follows:

> As the curve $(1)$ and $(2)$ intersect, $$\frac{n}{m} \neq \frac{m(n-1)}{n(m-1)} \tag{5}$$
>   which yields $$(m-n)(mn-m-n) \neq0 \tag{6}$$
>   and hence $$(mn-m-n) \neq 0 \tag{7}$$
>   implying $$x+y=0 \tag{8}$$

But I do not see how the $Eq.(5)$ can be obtained from $(4)$?

Comment: The condition (5) is a condition of non parallelism of the two lines or of non-colinearity of the direction vectors.

Comment: To get $\bf{(5)}$ you can also perform the operation $n.{\bf(1)}-m(n-1).{\bf(2)}$ on the system and try to get $x$ and distinguish 2 cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of the curves are $\frac{m}{n}$ and $\frac{n(m-1)}{m(n-1)}$.

As these intersect, they aren't parallel, so their slopes are unequal.

So $$\frac{m}{n}\ne\frac{n(m-1)}{m(n-1)} \implies m^2(n-1) \ne n^2(m-1) \implies m^2n-n^2m-m^2+n^2\ne0 \implies (m-n)(mn-m-n)\ne0 \implies(mn-m-n)\ne0 $$
as $m<n \implies m\ne n$